# Difference between nrows and df.head() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I was going through a tutorial where he taught first `df.head(25)` will give you the first 25 rows of the data, then he showed `pd.read_csv("__", nrows=25)`.

My question is what is the difference between these two options? If there is none then why there are 2 methods to get rows?

Thanks, Regards

Comment: are you sure its df.read_csv not pd.read_csv?

Comment: I think it is not `df.read_csv`, but `pd.read_csv`, right?

Comment: `.head(25)` shows the first 25 (or less, if size is less) rows of an *already* loaded dataframe. `nrows=25` passed to `pd.read_csv` attempts to read in at most 25 rows from the *file*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.head` assumes you already have a `pandas.DataFrame` read into your code and stored in the variable `df`; you can use `df.head(25)` to view the first 25 rows of this DataFrame.

`pandas.read_csv(filename, nrows=25)` would instead read data directly from a csv file located at `filename`, but only its first 25 rows. This data isn't already stored as a variable in your python instance, it is in the csv file.

Comment: well dataframe need not have more than 25 rows but yes :)

Comment: true, but what would be the point in running df.head(25) for a dataframe with 25 rows or less when you can just run df :)

Comment: when i don't know the size beforehand :)